# Process with dynamic id won't kill; has no parent

Tags: process, kill

I am trying to kill process like this:

```
root@xxx:~# ps -ef | grep mosquitto
root        3083    1912  0 11:59 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto mosquitto
root@xxx:~# kill 3083
-bash: kill: (3083) - No such process
ps -ef | grep mosquitto
root        3175    1912  0 12:00 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto mosquitto
root@xxx:~# ps -ef | grep mosquitto | head -c 16 | tail -c 4
3255root@xxx:~# kill $(ps -ef | grep mosquitto | head -c 16 | tail -c 4)
-bash: kill: (3290) - No such process
root@xxx:~# pgrep mosquitto | xargs -i pstree -ps {}
root@xxx:~#
```

How can I kill this process?

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is correct, but a little short on details.

```
root@xxx:~# ps -ef | grep mosquitto
root        3083    1912  0 11:59 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto mosquitto
```

Note that only one process is returned, with the command line `grep --color=auto mosquitto`. This is the `grep mosquitto` from your command line, to filter the `ps` output. Your shell most likely has an alias `grep=grep --color=auto`.

As soon as you get the next shell prompt, the `grep` from the previous command is already terminated, so there is no process with that pid to kill. When you execute the same command again, a new `grep` process is created, and it has a different PID from the previous `grep`.

The `grep` process may or may not be present in the output, it depends on the scheduling. But whenever you grep the output of `ps`, you should assume that `grep` process may appear in the output. If you do it manually, just ignore this result. If you need it in a script, there are several techniques to avoid it.

```
ps | grep mosquitto | grep -v grep
```

Ignores all lines containing `grep`-

```
ps | grep '[m]osquitto'
```

This doesn't create an additional process. It works because `[m]` as a character class that contains only the letter `m`, so it matches the intended pattern, but it doesn't match the `grep` argument.

Depending on what you are searching for, the `pgrep` command may also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Your process doesn't exist, Do such as :

```
ps ax  |grep  mosquitto|grep -v grep
```

Then you will not any process.

Comment: This just prints the kill help text

Comment: I tested by grep `vlc` and it kills vlc.

Comment: Ubuntu Server 20.04.2 LTS; I think it's not actually piping in the pid because of something mosquitto is doing?

Comment: Oh, you killed your PID and it cant get the PID. search by hand via `ps ax |grep mosquitto`

Comment: `root@xxx:~# ps ax |grep mosquitto
   5489 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto mosquitto
root@xxx:~# kill 5489
-bash: kill: (5489) - No such process`

Comment: You command only print `grep` process and if you apply `grep -v  grep`  , Then you see your process doesn't exist.

Comment: You can't kill a process if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Doh! Amend your answer and I'll accept! Clearly I'm an idiot, lol

Comment: I amended my answer.